# How to setup sublime 3 with react native so that when you click on the error and it jump to your code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3, react-native

How to setup sublime 3 with react native? it say add "add something like
REACT_EDITOR=atom to your .bashrc".

Where can add or edit REACT_EDITOR?

> PRO TIP
>
> When you see Red Box with stack trace, you can click any stack frame
> to jump to the source file. The packager will launch your editor of
> choice. It will first look at REACT_EDITOR environment variable, then
> at EDITOR. To set it up, you can add something like REACT_EDITOR=atom
> to your .bashrc.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same idea as you think of. You can do following:

1.We should make sure that sublime can be used in terminal command. So firstly we make the sublime terminal command.

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl`

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin`

then we run `subl sublime.txt` you will find it works.

2. We should change the `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` (if you has installed the oh my zsh) by adding

`export REACT_EDITOR=subl`

3.We restart the terminal and run react native project then click the error message. Amazing things will happen : )  have fun!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using **oh-my-zsh** and have already created a symbolic link from `subl` to `sublime` and have `vim` installed:

```
> vim ~/.zshrc
```

**add:**

```
export REACT_EDITOR=sublime
```

**reload .zshrc:**

```
> source ~/.zshrc
```

**restart app:** *(example for iOS)*

```
> react-native run-ios
```